# Postgres - Find duplicate values after lowering the values

Tags: postgresql, duplicates, postgresql-8.4

Hello StackOverflow users... I have a tricky situation and I have yet to find an answer. Maybe you can help me.

Database: PostgreSQL 8.4 (can't upgrade)

In this database, there is a **users** table. Sadly, the usernames that users can provide when they create a user profile is case sensitive, so a username of **Alex** is not the same as a username of **alex**.

There is a new system going out and username is no longer case sensitive. I'm trying to find all of the usernames that would be considered duplicates in the old system. This way we can reach out and have them update the usernames manually and then migrate their users to a newer system (without conflict of username).

I have the following query which will show me the counts of each username matching another with the "lower()" function.

```
select count(*), lower(username)
  from users
  where deleted = false
  group by lower(username) having count(*) > 1
```

This returns results like the following:

```
|count|lower   |
|-----+--------+
|3    |alex    |
|2    |george  |
```

What I need to do is get this data into a temp table and display all of those duplicate users and other details so that we have a list to go through.

I have part of the temp table figured out, but my main issue is: How do I get the distinct values of all of these duplicates? So in the long run, I get results that look like the following (and maybe even without a temp table if possible):

```
|lower  |username|
|-------+--------+
|alex   |Alex    |
|alex   |alex    |
|george |georGe  |
|george |George  |
```

Restrictions:

- I can't change the version of postgres from 8.4
- Some duplicates will have more than 2 hits (the most I've seen so far is 3)
- Since the users must be informed, there is no way to change the data other then to contact them prior (which is why the list is needed)

I appreciate any suggestions/feedback you may be able to provide.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following @Abelisto. Your example shows that each username duplicate is part of the function. I need to automate that search part of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this. Just generate your above list as a CTE, then join with it in the main query:

```
WITH dups AS (
    SELECT lower(username) uname, count(*) ucount 
    FROM users 
    WHERE deleted = false 
    GROUP BY lower(username) HAVING count(*) > 1)
SELECT username, uname, ucount 
FROM users INNER JOIN dups ON lower(username) = uname 
WHERE deleted = false
ORDER BY ucount DESC, uname ASC;

 username | uname  | ucount
----------+--------+--------
 Alex     | alex   |      3
 alex     | alex   |      3
 ALEX     | alex   |      3
 GeorGe   | george |      2
 george   | george |      2
(5 rows)
```

Or even simpler if you only want a bare list of the affected users:

```
SELECT username
FROM users 
WHERE deleted = false AND lower(username) IN (
    SELECT lower(username)
    FROM users
    WHERE deleted = false
    GROUP BY lower(username) HAVING count(*) > 1)
ORDER BY lower(username) ASC;

 username
----------
 Alex
 alex
 ALEX
 GeorGe
 george
(5 rows)
```

Comment: These look promising... I'll have an update within the next day or 2 and let you know. Thank you @Gil-Hamilton.

Comment: Thanks @Gil-Hamilton... that solution is just what I needed and saves me from having to create that temp table. It's also efficient and doesn't require any additional aggregation functions or tables really. Well written... Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I would usually use `string_agg`, but it looks like it's not supported in 8.4. There appears to be a workaround, but note that I haven't tested due to not having a local copy of 8.4 handy. Something like this should work:

```
select
  (max(u1.username)),
  array_to_string(array_agg(u2.username), ',') as duplicates
  from users u1
         inner join users u2 on u1.id < u2.id
         and lower(u1.username) = lower(u2.username)
         left join users u3 on u1.id > u3.id
         and lower(u1.username) = lower(u3.username)
         and u3.deleted = false
 where u1.deleted = false
   and u2.deleted = false
   and u3.id is null
 group by u1.id;
```

This will get the "earliest" user by ID (assuming there is a primary key that isn't `username`. It could be modified to show the actual lowercase username, and then the rest in the duplicates column.

Edit: to show a row for each duplicate:

```
select
  lower(u1.username),
  u2.username
  from users u1
         inner join users u2 on u1.id < u2.id
         and lower(u1.username) = lower(u2.username)
         left join users u3 on u1.id > u3.id
         and lower(u1.username) = lower(u3.username)
         and u3.deleted = false
 where u1.deleted = false
   and u2.deleted = false
   and u3.id is null
order by u1.username;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply @dliff... so this suffers from the same error I get when trying to manipulate the first sql statement using group...
Error: ERROR: column "u1.username" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

(this GROUP BY error is driving me a little batty lol)

Comment: I added ...**group by u1.username,u1.id** to the end... that gave me results, but the results are one to one (lower = alex, duplicates = Alex - but no other listing)

Comment: Ah, you need to only group by id, but use lower(max(u1.username)). I'll update my answer. Postgres doesn't know what there will only be 1 "u1.username" per u1.id.

Comment: That made it run without the error, but I'm still only getting 1 result per duplicate found. So if there is an Alex and an aleX, I only get 1 record instead of 2.

Comment: Isn't that the goal? With the array_agg, the 2nd column will list all of the duplicates. | daniel | Daniel,dAniel |

Comment: That is what the sql statement I provided is doing... list all usernames that have a matching duplicate (and it provides how many duplicates it found using count). I need to actually break that out so that each duplicate is separated and listed in it's own record in the result. If I have 2 usernames that match "alex" after the value has been lowered(), then I need to see 2 separate records.

Comment: Ah, I see. In that case you don't want a `group by`. A SQL join will create rows for each match without a group by. See updated answer.

Comment: Thanks for the input... makes sense. I still have much to learn. As far as the update goes, oddly it's showing some of the duplicates but only a single record for other duplicates. Is that possibly from using 3 tables? Maybe it's getting confused (or my version of postgres is just horrid).

Comment: Make sure you are selecting lower(u1.username) (it's ambiguous in my answer currently). I just tested this on a small local DB and it does produce what you're asking for. Are you certain that the single records have more duplicates than that?  The 3rd table is an anti-join, so that's not the issue. I updated my answer with those changes (run the 2nd query in my answer without the group by). Also, if you have spaces before or after the column that won't match with lower(). Maybe add trim() to the comparisons? It gets ride of trailing/leading spaces.

Comment: Thank you @dliff... I'll give that a shot and let you know.

Comment: Thanks again for the help @dliff... I appreciate your time and feedback on this and have picked up a couple of extra tricks from you. I think Gil's answer above marks the spot though.